# How to manage the back stack and navigate properly

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have 3 activities in app let say A, B and C. 
From A I can Navigate to B or C .  So the possible workflow has two ways:

1. A > > B >>C (Takes input and then starts calculation upon selected formula earlier in B)
2. A >> C>>  B and after selection of Formula it getsback to C

**Problem**

now in Case 1. If the user is navigated the shown path , A>B>C  I want user to navigate back in the same way I mean on backpress of B he should go to C and then to A :

but in 2nd case i want user should go to A from C , I mean opening of B in C should not navigate to B when user pressback . in other words if the user has navigated using my 2nd case he should come to A not to C .

how Can i handle this in this scenario .

Answer (score 0):

**Basically dont override backpress in your activity, let the android handle back activity for you.**

In First Usecase : when you navigate from MainActivity-->ActivityFormula-->ActivityMath. Here when you press back the sequence would be extractly reverse

In Second Usecase : When you navigate from  MainActivity-->ActivityMath , do not keep ActivityFormula in stack hence the back press wont go to  ActivityFormula.

Comment: how can i do not keep the stack in case 2 and How would app know that it is case 2

Answer (score 0):

@case 1, if you haven't closed A and B yourself, it will work as you want. Don't override anything.

@case 2, you can simply `finish()` C as soon as you start B. Write following code in your ActivityC:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: it seems like you have not read my question or you may have not understand it correctly

Comment: Ah. I read again. By "**2nd case he should come to A not to C**", do you want to skip B completely? Or you want to open it when you press back again (on A)?

Answer (score 0):

First Usecase :Intent from  `ActivityA`-->`ActivityB`-->`ActivityC`. Here when you press back the sequence would be extractly reverse

Second Usecase : When `nevigate  ActivityA`-->`ActivityC` , and use `finish();` when navigate '`ActivityC`'-->'`ActivityB`'

and in `ActivityB` `Intent` to `ActivityA` by using

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityC.this , ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(i);
         finish(); 
    }
```

Let me know.. If still not getting solution

Comment: In backpress in Activity B will create the ambigious condition. Let say when user navigate From Activity C to B and on Activity B he wanted to press the backbutton to go back to C but this will take him to Activity A which is not required

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Android behaviour. Pressing the BACK button (or calling `finish()`) will take the user back to the previous `Activity` in the stack. You don't have to do anything special to get this behaviour. It works like this by default.